# Android permissions to access media store

Tags: android

Are there any specific permissions needed to access android's mediastore?  I wrote a test app that could access all of the users photos - but I find this behavior unexpected.  It really seems like there should be some permissions to access this data.

Comment: Check your stack trace, if your app is missing a permission it will be written.

Comment: I don't think he is saying that his app doesn't function. He is wondering why applications are allowed to view the users images with no permissions.

Comment: @Tim exactly.  Just seems odd to me that no permissions are needed for photos, when permissions are needed for almost all other personal data.

Comment: I agree with you, especially considering that iOS was just in the news this week for apps being able to access the photos without properly informing the user that the apps do have that access.

Comment: Which android version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images(and video) taken with the device camera are stored in the External Storage (SD card on most devices) generally they are stored in `sdcard/dcim/Camera/`

On android there is no permission required to read from the external storage, this means that any application that is installed on the device could indeed have access to the photos that were taken with your device.

writing to the external storage does however require a permission, so if an application wanted to delete or change one of these files they would need to have that permission.

Though, to be honest unfortunately I think the permissions are a moot point. If there is a nice pretty icon, and promises of amazing things the general population will install anything regardless of what permissions it requires. For most people the permissions page is just that thing where you have to scroll down and press install.

Answer (score 8):

With android 4.4 i get this error message in logcat when reading an image via content url content://media/external/images/media/123 that is outside the /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera directory

```
... 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=1197, uid=10072 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

so newer android versions require permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE